# What is the best day of week and time to visit Cyprus mountain villages?

Tags: cyprus

We are currently on Cyprus and want to go to touristic mountain villages such as Kakopetria, Lefkara and Platres. We are interested in walking along streets, going to different shops (be it souvenir or not) and cafes; we are not interested in any religious activity (if any).

On what days of week and what time of day it is best to go there?

On one hand, most shops in other (not so touristic) areas of Cyprus are open till ~18.00-19.00, and are often closed on weekends (as may be expected). However, I think that touristic attractions may open later and/or on weekends. Also obviously around the noon it's very hot, and so this may be not the best time to go.

Also, Google maps advise me that the next Sunday, Aug 15, is a religious holiday; will it affect the situation in the villages?

Answer (score 5):

So we have gone there, even twice.

Regarding the time of day I now have a very clear answer: one should go there during normal daytime, roughly from 10 am to 6 pm. Many shops close at around 6 pm, so no point waiting till evening. Moreover, if you intend to drive back to your place of stay at the evening, beware of driving the winding mountain roads when it's already dark, so better start your back journey at least half an hour before the sunset.

Regarding the day of week, I do not have such a clear answer; we have been there on weekdays and did not see any problems. At the same time, at least a couple of wineries listed that they are closed on Sundays, so probably weekdays are indeed a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, this may help someone else in the future.